# jQuery remove specific input value before submiting

Tags: jquery, forms, input, form-submit, default-value

Here is what I have:

```
<form method="get" action="" name="advsearch">
  <input type="hidden" name="query" value="">
  <div class="formelement-01">
    <select name="product" size="1" onclick="bq()">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Select Brand</option>
      <option value="brand 1">brand 1</option>
      <option value="brand 2">brand 2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="formelement-02">
    <select name="cut" size="1" onchange="bq()">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Select Product Type</option>
      <option value="product 1">product 1</option>
      <option value="product 2">product 2</option>
      <option value="product 3">product 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="formelement-03">
    <input onfocus="if (this.value == 'Enter keywords') this.value = '';" value="Enter keywords" type="text" name="keyword" id="key" onChange="bq()">
  </div>
  <div class="formelement-04">
    <input type="image" src="images/submit.gif" value="Submit" name="Submit" id="sbmit">
  </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function bq() {
   document.advsearch.query.value = document.advsearch.cut.value + " "  + document.advsearch.product.value + " "  + document.advsearch.keyword.value;}
</script>
```

The form works fine, but if I do not replace the value "Enter keywords" with something else, it gets submitted along with the options I choose.

How do I prevent this specific value, "Enter keywords", from submitting? Please note, the form should be able to submit any other value, just not this one.

I hope there is somebody who can help with this.

Thank you in advance.
Elena

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need Html placeholder instead of doing old text validations.

```
<input type="text" name="mytextbox" placeholder="Enter keywords">
```

See here for [**examples and demo**](http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-placeholder.php)

Comment: you are a lifesaver! I wish I asked sooner. Thank you so much!

Comment: @elenanincevic Glad to save your time :) Mark the green tick if you found helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try with **placeholder** like

```
<input value="" placeholder="Enter Keywords" type="text" name="keyword" id="key" onChange="bq()">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `placeholder` property of input type but remember this placeholder property will not work on IE.

SO use the following code:

```
<form method="get" action="" name="advsearch" onSubmit="fun()">
```

add a function on form. Then use the following script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function fun() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("key");
    if(ele.value == "Enter keywords") {
       ele.value = "";
    } 
    return true;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You are right. It works on ie10, but not older. Thank you!! I will try it your way.

Comment: I am not sure why, but this solution is not working on the form above. I am not as good with JS, but I assume it has to do with the onchange function that is already applied to each select and input box. If you have a quick fix on that, let me know. Thank you.